# Cannot update newly added User field using wp_update_user

Tags: users, wp-update-post, wp-user-query

I want to add a new attribute to the wp_user table, "twitter_id" for example.

I added the new column to the `wp_user` table, and it is added correctly. I get the current user (as I want to edit the value of the logged in user) and the `wp_update_user`.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
    
$user->twitter_id = "123";

$response = wp_update_user($user);
```

If I echo out $user->twitter_id, it properly shows the updated value, but the DB does not update.

if I change `twitter_id` to an existing field, the db is updated with the above code just fine.

How do I update custom fields?

Comment: Why are you adding columns to the `wp_users` table? You should be using [user meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/).

Comment: I am fairly new to wordpress, since every user needs one (and it has to be unique) I thought the best place to put it, would be on the user object.  Whats the benefit to using user_meta over storing it on the actual user?

Comment: It allows you to use the WP API to set/get user meta and avoid the very problem you're having now.

Comment: So the Wordpress is built to ignore any extra fields, unless using the meta data?

Comment: Yes, wp_users is "as-is".  you should use user meta for your case.

Comment: A common way to do this, e.g. as used by the Yoast SEO plugin, is to hook the [user_contactmethods](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_contactmethods/) filter and add Twitter to that, then it's automatically stored in user meta and shown on user forms. [Here's their filter](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/15.3/admin/class-admin.php#L268) and [the add_filter line](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/15.3/admin/class-admin.php#L59).